# Azure VPN with PaaS?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to use site-to-site vpn with paas cloud services in azure? I have a VM in azure and it seems to work just fine but can't seem to find anything in config (or wherever) about vpn for cloud services....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes. You create the network first, then, configure the cloud service to deploy into that network.

[Here are instructions that should help](http://michaelwasham.com/2012/08/06/connecting-web-or-worker-roles-to-a-simple-virtual-network-in-windows-azure/)